# How to model this part ? absolute no clue

Tags: modeling

[image]

Any tips ? absolute no idea how to do it  (rounded)

Greetings

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be unique and identifying and summarize what the issue is, so that visitors can at a glance understand broadly what your post is about from the question list. Please use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors will see, and weights on their decision to open your question or not, so the number of answers you might get depends heavily on it.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do it, I would model it keeping it as low poly as possible and using only quads. Then, add both a **Solidify**, to give it thickness, and a **Subdivision Surface** modifier on top of it. You could reorder your modifiers to see what gives you the best result. To sharpen the pointy tip at the top of the image, I would use edge creases (*Shift+E* in edit mode) or add support loops (*Ctrl+R* in edit mode).

You might be interested at searching **blender subdivision surface modeling** tutorials online.